# XML::LibXML's notion of a text node's parent

Tags: xml, perl, xml-libxml

Something seems odd here.

In the example below, I'm accessing text nodes via an XPath query ( `//book/isbn/text()` ). The `text()` is necessary to coerce `XML::LibXML` into allowing me to use the `XML::LibXML::Text` methods.

To get to the parent node though, I have to invoke the `parentNode` method twice to get the true parent node (`<book>` in this case):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = XML::LibXML->new->parse_string( << 'MAIN' );
  <library>
    <book>
      <title>Perl Best Practices</title>
      <author>Damian Conway</author>
      <isbn>0596001738</isbn>
      <pages>542</pages>
      <image src="http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/covers/perlbp.s.gif"
             width="145" height="190" />
    </book>
    <book>
      <title>Perl Cookbook, Second Edition</title>
      <author>Tom Christiansen</author>
      <author>Nathan Torkington</author>
      <isbn>0596003137</isbn>
      <pages>964</pages>
      <image src="http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/covers/perlckbk2.s.gif"
             width="145" height="190" />
    </book>
  </library>
MAIN

foreach my $isbn ( $xml->findnodes( '//book/isbn/text()' ) ) {

    # Do something with $isbn->setData()

    my $book = $isbn->parentNode->parentNode;  # My daddy's daddy is my daddy?
    print $book->toString;
}
```

#### Output

```
<book>
      <title>Perl Best Practices</title>
      <author>Damian Conway</author>
      <isbn>0596001738</isbn>
      <pages>542</pages>
      <image src="http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/covers/perlbp.s.gif" width="145" height="190"/>
    </book><book>
      <title>Perl Cookbook, Second Edition</title>
      <author>Tom Christiansen</author>
      <author>Nathan Torkington</author>
      <isbn>0596003137</isbn>
      <pages>964</pages>
      <image src="http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/covers/perlckbk2.s.gif" width="145" height="190"/>
    </book>
```

---

So:

- is my understanding of XML nodes incorrect in assuming that `//isbn` and `//isbn/text()` are the same node, or
- is this a bug in [`XML::LibXML`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aLibXML)'s `parentNode` method?

Comment: Note that `isbn[text()]` will select isbn elements that have text nodes, if that's what you want. `$isbn->textContent()` will get the text context, and `$isbn->parentNode()` will get the book element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each element in a XML document is a node. If that element contains text (e.g. `<isbn>019328373476</isbn>`), then it is a child node (of type text, as opposed to element) of that element.

It is not a bug in XML::LibXML's parentNode method.

Comment: Well, that explains the behavior I'm seeing. I'm curious as to why this design decision was taken though. Perhaps you could provide an example to illustrate why it makes sense to make `//node` and `//node/text()` two different nodes

Comment: You may want to look into the DOM standard at [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR)

Comment: `<a>foo<b/>bar</a>` — they are separate nodes so that you can address `foo`, `<b/>` and `bar`.